# How to design or somehow get a custom WindowBar and grip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, material-design, visualdesigner

Like in Visual Studio, let's say the ToolBox, it has a blue draggable WindowBar like this:

[image: ToolBox]

or like this:

[image: VerticalGrip]

Is there a DLL to get one, or an easy way to make it?

Comment: You may want to look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.rebar.gripper?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: OP asks for an 'easy way' to create a grip on a control. VisualStyleRenderer is included in .NET just for these adornments. Question is 100% on topic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render some control to look like some system element, like a a grip, you can use a suitable [`VisualStyleRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

As you can see there is a huge number! - Here is how you would add a [VisualStyleElement.Rebar.Gripper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.rebar.gripper?view=netframework-4.7.2) to a `Panel`:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // any other drawing before..
    DrawVisualStyleElementRebarGripper1(e);
}
```

Here is a typical implementation of the method to call:

```
public void DrawVisualStyleElementRebarGripper1(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (VisualStyleRenderer.IsElementDefined(
        VisualStyleElement.Rebar.Gripper.Normal))
    {
        VisualStyleRenderer renderer =
                new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Rebar.GripperVertical.Normal);
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                            20,  (int)e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height);
        renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, rectangle1);
    }
    //else
    //    e.Graphics.DrawString("This element is not defined in the current visual style.",
    //            this.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10));
}
```

Result:

[image]

Make sure to call the rendering method **after** any other paint action so it won't get painted over

Note that are **two** of them: `GripperVertical` and `Gripper`; on my system (W10) they look the same but on other systems they may not!

If you actually want a custom grip style you could paint it with a suitable hatchpattern brush; that would look the same across all systems, which may be what you want. But it would also mean that it will not always integrate with the rest of windows; this solution will always use the style of the current machine.

**Update:**

If you want to allow dragging the control you can use Vanethrane's answer for the basic functionality. For better UX also make sure to consider these points:

- Use all three events, `MouseDown, -Move and -Up`.
- Change the `Cursor` from `Default` to `Hand` and `SizeAll`
- Test if you are in the **grip area**
- Before moving bring the control to the **top of the z-order** with `BringToFront` to avoid passing under any other control
- In the `MouseDown` store the current position **twice**; once for moving and once for **restoring** in case the final location is **invalid**
- often you want to use a **grid** to control the final position and...
- ..often you want to have the control **align** itself 'magnetically' with the closest neighbour. Use `MouseUp` to change the final position accordingly..

I suggest to bundle all the functionality into a `DraggableControl` **class**.

Comment: Thanks, Works like a Charm :)

Comment: Note the updates I have added!

Comment: Nice! by the way, I realized it's probably easier if you just make a picturebox with grip dots and use Vanethrane's answer to make it draggable

Comment: Yes, this is only about the looks. You can combine both answers in the same controls to get looks and behaviour..

Comment: Yes i Did. and It works, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

super easy. here:

create the desired control, name it grip. put these in the mouse down and mouse move methods respectively

```
 private Point Mouselocation;


    private void grip_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Mouselocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void grip_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            grip.Left = e.X + grip.Left - Mouselocation.X;
            grip.Top = e.Y + grip.Top - Mouselocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

note, that this will move a single control. to move the whole form you need to implement this on the form itself

Comment: Thanks though I Didn't want to know how to drag it. I wanted to know how to make a grip itself (the design)